# Create a new Hyper-V VM (using WMI) with specific hardware

Tags: c#, wmi, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm wanting to create a new Hyper-V VM with a determined amount of RAM, network card, number of processor cores, and attach a VHD file to the IDE controller.

The problem is that the `Msvm_ResourceAllocationSettingData` is not very easy to work with. The code I'm using doesn't work (this is code to attach a VHD to an existing VM, however I would also like to use it when creating a new VHD too).

```
public void AttachVhd(IdeChannel ideChannel, String vhdPath) {

        // Get VirtualSystemSettingData
        ManagementObject vssd = this.GetVirtualSystemSettingData();

        // Get the IDE Controller
        ManagementObject ideController = this.GetResourceAllocationSettingData(ResourceType.IdeController, ResourceSubType.IdeController);

        // Create synthetic disk:
        ManagementObject syntheticDiskRasd = this.GetResourceAllocationSettingData(ResourceType.Disk, ResourceSubType.DiskSynthetic);
        syntheticDiskRasd["Parent"]  = ideController.Path;
        syntheticDiskRasd["Address"] = ideChannel == IdeChannel.Primary ? "0" : "1";

        this.AddVirtualSystemResources(syntheticDiskRasd);

        // Attach it
        ManagementObject vhdRasd = this.GetResourceAllocationSettingData(ResourceType.StorageExtent, ResourceSubType.Vhd); ;
        vhdRasd["Parent"]     = syntheticDiskRasd.Path;
        vhdRasd["Connection"] = new String[] { vhdPath };

        this.AddVirtualSystemResources( vhdRasd );

        // Cleanup
        vhdRasd.Dispose();
        syntheticDiskRasd.Dispose();
        ideController.Dispose();
        vssd.Dispose();
    }

    private ManagementObject GetResourceAllocationSettingData(ResourceType resourceType, ResourceSubType resourceSubType)
    {
        String desiredSubType = ResourceSubTypeStrings.GetString(resourceSubType); // Scout.Common.Extensions.GetDescription( resourceType );

        using(ManagementObjectCollection settingsDatas = _vm.GetRelated("Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData"))
        foreach(ManagementObject settingData in settingsDatas)
        {
            using(ManagementObjectCollection rasds = settingData.GetRelated("Msvm_ResourceAllocationSettingData"))
            foreach(ManagementObject rasd in rasds)
            {
                ResourceType rasdResourceType    = (ResourceType)(UInt16)rasd["ResourceType"];
                String       rasdResourceSubType =               (String)rasd["ResourceSubType"];
                String       rasdOtherType       =               (String)rasd["OtherResourceType"];

                if( rasdResourceType == resourceType && rasdResourceSubType == desiredSubType )
                {
                    return rasd;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void AddVirtualSystemResources(ManagementObject rasd)
    {
        using (ManagementObject vmService = HyperV.GetManagementService())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = vmService.GetMethodParameters("AddVirtualSystemResources");
            inParams["TargetSystem"]         = _vm;
            inParams["ResourceSettingsData"] = rasd.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = vmService.InvokeMethod("AddVirtualSystemResources", inParams, options: null);

            String[]            addedResources = (String[])outParams["NewResources"];
            OperationReturnCode returnValue    = (OperationReturnCode)(UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"];

            if (returnValue == OperationReturnCode.JobStarted)
            {
                String jobPath = (String)outParams["Job"];
                HyperV.MonitorJob(jobPath);
            }
            else if (returnValue == OperationReturnCode.Completed)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException( returnValue.ToString() );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than find your problem, can I point you to an example that works?

See `WmiCalls.DeployVirtualMachine` in [my Apache CloudStack Hyper-V plugin](https://github.com/lafferty/cshv3/blob/master/plugins/hypervisors/hyperv/DotNet/ServerResource/HypervResource/WmiCalls.cs)

Post a comment if you need additional detail, and I will update the answer.